# Autohotkey, toggling a boolean doesn't work

Tags: autohotkey

I have a script that is supposed to emulate the Colemak keyboard layout. I want to be able to toggle the layout with Win+Space

Here's the script:

```java
colemak = true

#If %colemak% = true
hotkeys...
#If

#Space::ChangeLayout()

ChangeLayout()
{
    colemak := !colemak
    if (colemak = false) {
        MsgBox Colemak deactivated.
    } else {
        MsgBox Colemak activated.
    }
}
```

When I press Win+Space, the colemak variable doesn't change, it stays at `true`. What am I doing wrong here?

Also, I want to have some kind of feedback that tells the user that the layout changed. MsgBox isn't really the thing I am looking for because it requires the user to press ok. I want a popup or something similar that just tells the user that it changed without any interaction required or possible. What are some possibilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. In order to declare a variable, you need to use the `:=` operator. So instead of initially declaring `colemak = true`, you need `colemak := true`.
2. The function `ChangeLayout()` has its own scope in which the initial declaration of the global variable `colemak` is not visible. In order to fix this, you need to make `colemak` a "super global" variable by adding `global` in front of it.

Final code:

```
global colemak := true

#If %colemak% = true
hotkeys...
#If

#Space::ChangeLayout()

ChangeLayout()
{
    colemak := !colemak
    if (colemak = false) {
        MsgBox Colemak deactivated.
    } else {
        MsgBox Colemak activated.
    }
}
```

[Source](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=29227)

Comment: In order to test that, could you please include the rest of the script?

Comment: The problem were the % signs, without them, it works!